# python regular expression for multiple string values

Tags: python, regex, expression

so my issues is that im receiving values from a serial port.
The values could be any of the flowing.

BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1412010472R-77,ATC005:T1412010460R-70,SU0003;Q6V8.9S0C11.5*xx
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1413824282R-102,ATC003:T1413824274R-98,SU001G;Q0V14.0D00*x

their is minor chnages in the out put but the biggest difference is the second line has the value D00 instead of S0

So this serial out will update me with changes to sensors and the D00 is for digital output but S0 is for the fan speed.

So my question is i have written a regular expression if i receive the first serial output that has the S0 value but if i then receive the D00 the regular expression will break.

I want to be able to write it so if it doesn't have the S0 value it would then look for the D00 value instead.

thank you for any help or advise in advance. im not sure where i should be looking or what direction i should be taking.

The code below checks the serial output and then runs the regular expression, if it find a match it then inserts that into the data base.

CODE BELOW IS PYTHON

import serial, string, MySQLdb, re

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="walnut_farm")
cur = db.cursor() 

serialPort = 'COM4' # BAUD Rate is 9600 as default
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.setPort(serialPort)
#ser.setBaudrate(115200) Enable if BAUD is not deault value 

try:
    ser.open()
except: 
    print('Port Error!')

else:
    while True:
        try:
            ardString = ser.readline()
            Serial_Output = ardString

            p = re.compile(ur'^BASE_RAD: NEW,(.*)#T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*):T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*);Q(\d*)V(\d*\.?\d*)S(\d*)C(\d*\.?\d*)(.*)') # here is the regular expressions i created from this link http://regex101.com/r/dP6fE1/1

            Serial_Results = re.match(p, Serial_Output)


            # Assigning variables to the array values
            Base_ID = Serial_Results.group(1)
            Base_Time_Stamp = Serial_Results.group(2)
            Base_Signal = Serial_Results.group(3)
            Repeater_ID = Serial_Results.group(4)
            Repeater_Time_Stamp = Serial_Results.group(5)
            Repeater_Signal = Serial_Results.group(6)
            Sensor_ID = Serial_Results.group(7)
            Sensor_Sequence = Serial_Results.group(8)
            Sensor_Input_Voltage = Serial_Results.group(9)
            Sensor_Wind_Speed = Serial_Results.group(10)
            Sensor_Temperature = Serial_Results.group(11)
            Checksum = Serial_Results.group(12)

            # Execute the SQL query to INSERT the above variables into the Database
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO serial_values (Base_ID, Base_Time_Stamp, Base_Signal, Repeater_ID, Repeater_Time_Stamp, Repeater_Signal, Sensor_ID, Sensor_Sequence,  Sensor_Input_Voltage, Sensor_Wind_Speed, Sensor_Temperature, Checksum) VALUES ("'+Base_ID+'", "'+Base_Time_Stamp+'", "'+Base_Signal+'", "'+Repeater_ID+'", "'+Repeater_Time_Stamp+'", "'+Repeater_Signal+'", "'+Sensor_ID+'", "'+Sensor_Sequence+'",  "'+Sensor_Input_Voltage+'", "'+Sensor_Wind_Speed+'", "'+Sensor_Temperature+'", "'+Checksum+'")')

            db.commit()
            #ser.close()

        except Exception:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this, if my interpretation is right. It's a starting point, you then have to include your mysql insert into the database.

```
import re

def get_output_parameters(serial_output):
    p = re.compile(ur'^BASE_RAD: NEW,(.*)#T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*):T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*);Q(\d*)V(\d*\.?\d*)S(\d*)C(\d*\.?\d*)(.*)') # here is the regular expressions i created from this link http://regex101.com/r/dP6fE1/1
    p2 = re.compile(ur'^BASE_RAD: NEW,(.*)#T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*):T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*);Q(\d*)V(\d*\.?\d*)D(\d*)(.*)')

    Serial_Results = re.match(p, serial_output)
    digital_out = False
    if not Serial_Results:
        Serial_Results = re.match(p2, serial_output)
        digital_out = True

    # Assigning variables to the array values
    Base_ID = Serial_Results.group(1)
    Base_Time_Stamp = Serial_Results.group(2)
    Base_Signal = Serial_Results.group(3)
    Repeater_ID = Serial_Results.group(4)
    Repeater_Time_Stamp = Serial_Results.group(5)
    Repeater_Signal = Serial_Results.group(6)
    Sensor_ID = Serial_Results.group(7)
    Sensor_Sequence = Serial_Results.group(8)
    Sensor_Input_Voltage = Serial_Results.group(9)
    Sensor_Wind_Speed = Serial_Results.group(10)
    Sensor_Temperature = Serial_Results.group(11)
    if not digital_out:
        Checksum = Serial_Results.group(12)

    print Sensor_Temperature


Serial_Output = "BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1412010472R-77,ATC005:T1412010460R-70,SU0003;Q6V8.9S0C11.5*xx"
Serial_Output2 = "BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1413824282R-102,ATC003:T1413824274R-98,SU001G;Q0V14.0D00*x"

get_output_parameters(Serial_Output)
get_output_parameters(Serial_Output2)
```