# Python read from telnet not capturing all the data

Tags: python, loops, telnet

So i asked a question in relation to running multiple regular expressions  from a seial stream. [python regular expression for multiple string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485313/python-regular-expression-for-multiple-string-values/26503170#26503170)

Now i have had to move to getting the data from a Telnet stream instread of a direct serial connection

It is kind of working and im able to get results posted to my database and get the two available regular expressions to work.

The issue is that its missing parts, so at times it the Telent Stream output 7 new lines of updates the code i have written will pick up the first on and misses the rest, seems like its hanging on something or is it just it cant process the Telnet stream and post to the database quick enough.

Here is the code so far. (i have taken out the telnet address for security reasons but will provide via email if needed) **Im using python 2.7**

```html
import serial, string, MySQLdb, re, pdb, telnetlib


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="walnut_farm")
cur = db.cursor() 

HOST = "this is the ip or the telnet server i have removed"
PORT = "7001"

p = re.compile(ur'^BASE_RAD: NEW,(.*)#T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*):T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*);Q(\d*)V(\d*\.?\d*)S(\d*)C(\d*\.?\d*)(.*)') # Wind Speed and Temp
p2 = re.compile(ur'^BASE_RAD: NEW,(.*)#T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*):T(\d*)R-(\d*),(.*);Q(\d*)V(\d*\.?\d*)D(\d*)(.*)') # Digital Output


def Push_Results_To_Database():
 # Assigning variables to the array values
 Base_ID = Serial_Results.group(1)
 Base_Time_Stamp = Serial_Results.group(2)
 Base_Signal = Serial_Results.group(3)
 Repeater_ID = Serial_Results.group(4)
 Repeater_Time_Stamp = Serial_Results.group(5)
 Repeater_Signal = Serial_Results.group(6)
 Sensor_ID = Serial_Results.group(7)
 Sensor_Sequence = Serial_Results.group(8)
 Sensor_Input_Voltage = Serial_Results.group(9)
   
 if not digital_out:
  Sensor_Wind_Speed = Serial_Results.group(10)
  Sensor_Temperature = Serial_Results.group(11)
  Checksum = Serial_Results.group(12)
  # Execute the SQL query to INSERT the above variables into the Database
  cur.execute('INSERT INTO serial_values (Base_ID, Base_Time_Stamp, Base_Signal, Repeater_ID, Repeater_Time_Stamp, Repeater_Signal, Sensor_ID, Sensor_Sequence,  Sensor_Input_Voltage, Sensor_Wind_Speed, Sensor_Temperature, Checksum) VALUES ("'+Base_ID+'", "'+Base_Time_Stamp+'", "'+Base_Signal+'", "'+Repeater_ID+'", "'+Repeater_Time_Stamp+'", "'+Repeater_Signal+'", "'+Sensor_ID+'", "'+Sensor_Sequence+'",  "'+Sensor_Input_Voltage+'", "'+Sensor_Wind_Speed+'", "'+Sensor_Temperature+'", "'+Checksum+'")')
  db.commit()

 if digital_out:
  Sensor_Digital_Input = Serial_Results.group(10)
  Checksum = Serial_Results.group(11)
  # Execute the SQL query to INSERT the above variables into the Database
  cur.execute('INSERT INTO serial_values (Base_ID, Base_Time_Stamp, Base_Signal, Repeater_ID, Repeater_Time_Stamp, Repeater_Signal, Sensor_ID, Sensor_Sequence,  Sensor_Input_Voltage, Sensor_Digital_Input, Checksum) VALUES ("'+Base_ID+'", "'+Base_Time_Stamp+'", "'+Base_Signal+'", "'+Repeater_ID+'", "'+Repeater_Time_Stamp+'", "'+Repeater_Signal+'", "'+Sensor_ID+'", "'+Sensor_Sequence+'",  "'+Sensor_Input_Voltage+'", "'+Sensor_Digital_Input+'", "'+Checksum+'")') 
  db.commit()

try:
 tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,PORT)
 
except: 
 print('Port Error!')

else:
 while True:
   #pdb.set_trace()
   tn.write('ls \r\n')
   data = '' 
   while data.find('#') == -1:
        data = tn.read_very_eager()
   ardString = data
   print data
   Serial_Output = ardString

   #pdb.set_trace()
   
   #for Serial_Output in Serial_Output.splitlines():
   if re.match(p, Serial_Output):
    print "Match For Wind Speed and Temperature"
    digital_out = False
    Serial_Results = re.match(p, Serial_Output)
    Push_Results_To_Database()
    continue

   elif re.match(p2, Serial_Output):
    print "Match for Digital Output"
    digital_out = True
    Serial_Results = re.match(p2, Serial_Output)
    Push_Results_To_Database()
    continue
   else:
    continue



#[1]  `ATC001`     = Base_ID
#[2]  `1412010472` = Base_Time_Stamp (EPOC TIME) 
#[3]  `77`         = Base_Signal
#[4]  `ATC005`     = Repeater_ID
#[5]  `1412010460` = Repeater_Time_Stamp
#[6]  `70`         = Repeater_Signal
#[7]  `SU0003`     = Sensor_ID
#[8]  `6`          = Sensor_Sequence
#[9]  `8.9`        = Sensor_Input_Voltage
#[10] `0`          = Sensor_Wind_Speed
#[11] `11.5`       = Sensor_Temperature
#[12] `*xx`        = Checksum

# http://regex101.com/r/dP6fE1/1
```

Here is an example of the Telnet output.

```js
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254671R-77,ATC003:T1414254671R-70,SU0014;Q6V13.9D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254676R-103,ATC004:T1414254655R-70,SU0017;Q5V13.9D00*x
x
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254691R-77,ATC003:T1414254688R-80,SU001D;Q6V13.1D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254696R-103,ATC004:T1414254692R-70,SU0016;Q0V13.5D00*x
x
BASE_RAD: ATC003 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254731R-77,ATC003:T1414254713R-72,SU0015;Q8V13.4D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254741R-77,ATC003:T1414254728R-71,SU001F;Q6V13.1D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254761R-77,ATC003:T1414254745R-70,SU001H;Q9V13.1D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254781R-77,ATC003:T1414254765R-72,SU0013;Q7V13.4D00*xx
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254791R-77,ATC003:T1414254770R-70,SU001G;Q6V13.1D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC003 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254816R-103,ATC004:T1414254802R-70,SU0002;Q9V12.9S3C13
.0*xx
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254831R-77,ATC003:T1414254830R-81,SU0019;Q7V13.6D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC003 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254852R-93,ATC005:T1414254843R-70,SU001C;Q0V13.3D00*xx
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC003 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC003 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254892R-93,ATC005:T1414254880R-70,SU0003;Q3V13.2S5C11.
1*xx
BASE_RAD: NEW,ATC001#T1414254896R-103,ATC004:T1414254885R-70,SU0018;Q8V13.2D00*x
x
BASE_RAD: ATC003 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC005 has no more samples
BASE_RAD: ATC004 has no more samples
```

So just wondering if anyone can spot where i may have gone wrong and why it would be hanging/ missing telnet results.

Thanks for any advise or tips.

Answer (score 0):

So just after posting this i have solved my issue, I will leave this up hear just in case it helps anyone else.

Here is the block of code from above

```js
tn.write('ls \r\n')
   data = '' 
   while data.find('#') == -1:
        data = tn.read_very_eager()
   ardString = data
   print data
   Serial_Output = ardString
```

Now i have added tn.write('ls \r\n') below the telnet read line.

data = tn.read_very_eager()
tn.write('ls \r\n')

So not that i need to return a new line as the output from the telnet session is already doing this but it stops the read of the telnet line so it does not hang.

Hope this makes sense and helps some one.
Please post me a message if i have made a mistake or need help with something similar.